# Installation of unimcrp on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

As per the instructions given in url below:

https://code.google.com/p/unimrcp/wiki/asteriskUniMRCP

```
[root@localhost uni-ast-package-1.0.0]# ls
asterisk             get-answer.sh  modules-install.sh
asterisk-install.sh  INSTALL        unimrcp
asterisk-unimrcp     modules        unimrcp-install.sh

./asterisk--install.sh
./unimrcp-install.sh
```

are successful.
But while running the script ./modules-install.sh
It displays the following error:

```
/usr/include/errno.h:55: error: declaration for parameter
âprogram_invocation_nameâ but no such parameter
/usr/include/bits/errno.h:47: error: declaration for parameter
â__errno_locationâ but no such parameter
res_speech_unimrcp.c:1433: error: expected â{â at end of input
make[1]: *** [res_speech_unimrcp.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory
/Akatsuki/uni-ast-package-1.0.0/modules/res-speech-unimrcp'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check INSTALL document in directory. Very likly it is for other asterisk version.

Anyway this is not supported module and all question have be addressed to developers of this module(person who do install have be expert)

Comment: Thank you but i have solved this problem by installing unimrcp-deps.tar.gz